# QGIS CSV not geolocating correctly

Tags: csv, geolocation, qgis

I've been adding text layers without issue in 3.22.3-Białowieża and files that I concert from Excel position in the wrong location.
I've added Shape files and some text (csv) but the files that don't plot properly...never work.  I saw a post about restarting the program but that doesnt fix the problem
Here is a picture of the plotted position and example of the data...The red is from the ESRI Shape and green the CSV. Also an example of the CSV data...

[image: Shape plot versus CSV]

```
"EXPED_CD","DATE","LAT","LONG"
"68006","1968-01-25T19:00",44.433331,-57.116661
"68006","1968-01-25T20:00",44.433331,-56.796669
"68006","1968-01-25T21:00",44.413879,-56.495022
"68006","1968-01-25T22:00",44.394409,-56.193272
"68006","1968-01-26T00:00",44.37167,-55.575001
"68006","1968-01-26T01:00",44.333328,-55.25
"68006","1968-01-26T07:00",44.25,-55.333328
"68006","1968-01-26T08:00",44.099998,-55.549999
"68006","1968-01-26T09:00",43.933331,-55.73333
"68006","1968-01-26T10:00",43.75,-55.916672
"68006","1968-01-26T11:00",43.566669,-56.066669
"68006","1968-01-26T12:00",43.415001,-56.26667
"68006","1968-01-26T13:00",43.263329,-56.466671
"68006","1968-01-26T14:00",43.10833,-56.666672
"68006","1968-01-26T15:00",42.964581,-56.831669
"68006","1968-01-27T02:00",42.386669,-57.369999
"68006","1968-01-27T03:00",42.255001,-57.544998
"68006","1968-01-27T04:00",42.105,-57.68716
"68006","1968-01-27T05:00",41.943939,-57.843941
"68006","1968-01-27T06:00",41.757069,-58.034851
"68006","1968-01-27T07:00",41.570202,-58.225761
"68006","1968-01-27T08:00",41.383339,-58.416672
"68006","1968-01-27T09:00",41.22084,-58.5825
"68006","1968-01-27T10:00",41.058331,-58.748329
"68006","1968-01-27T11:00",40.903332,-58.900002
"68006","1968-01-27T12:00",40.700001,-59.099998
"68006","1968-01-28T01:00",40.145,-59.738331
"68006","1968-01-28T02:00",39.959999,-59.88834
"68006","1968-01-28T03:00",39.775002,-60.03833
"68006","1968-01-28T04:00",39.587502,-60.202499
"68006","1968-01-28T05:00",39.400002,-60.366661
"68006","1968-01-28T06:00",39.23333,-60.541618
"68006","1968-01-28T07:00",39.066669,-60.716671
"68006","1968-01-28T10:00",39.025002,-60.60833
"68006","1968-01-28T11:00",38.888329,-60.805
"68006","1968-01-28T12:00",38.73333,-60.963329
"68006","1968-01-28T13:00",38.575001,-61.131672
"68006","1968-01-29T07:00",38,-62.599998
"68006","1968-01-29T08:00",37.816669,-62.633339
"68006","1968-01-29T09:00",37.625,-62.681671
"68006","1968-01-29T10:00",37.433331,-62.73
"68006","1968-01-29T11:00",37.25,-62.783329
"68006","1968-01-29T12:00",37.049999,-62.833328
"68006","1968-01-29T13:00",36.818329,-62.898331
"68006","1968-01-29T14:00",36.616661,-62.96167
"68006","1968-01-30T03:00",35.833328,-63.41333
"68006","1968-01-30T04:00",35.647049,-63.549019
"68006","1968-01-30T05:00",35.460758,-63.6847
"68006","1968-01-30T06:00",35.274479,-63.820389
"68006","1968-01-30T07:00",35.088188,-63.956081
"68006","1968-01-30T08:00",34.901909,-64.091766
"68006","1968-01-30T10:00",34.529381,-64.363037
"68006","1968-01-30T11:00",34.343121,-64.498787
"68006","1968-01-30T12:00",34.14167,-64.599998
"68006","1968-01-30T13:00",33.970791,-64.699997
"68006","1968-01-30T14:00",33.799999,-64.800003
"68006","1968-01-30T17:00",33.616661,-64.916656
"68006","1968-01-30T18:00",33.395,-64.949997
"68006","1968-01-30T19:00",33.183331,-65.008171
"68006","1968-01-31T03:00",32.818329,-65.025002
"68006","1968-01-31T04:00",32.64167,-65.099998
"68006","1968-01-31T05:00",32.451981,-65.17775
"68006","1968-01-31T13:00",31.658331,-65.041656
"68006","1968-01-31T15:00",31.229071,-65.087463
"68006","1968-01-31T16:00",31.01453,-65.110397
"68006","1968-01-31T17:00",30.799999,-65.133331
"68006","1968-01-31T18:00",30.58333,-65.133331
"68006","1968-02-01T03:00",30.11167,-65.316673
"68006","1968-02-01T04:00",29.92333,-65.28833
"68006","1968-02-01T05:00",29.72665,-65.225517
"68006","1968-02-01T06:00",29.529961,-65.162712
"68006","1968-02-01T07:00",29.33333,-65.099998
"68006","1968-02-01T08:00",29.133329,-65.029114
"68006","1968-02-01T09:00",28.933331,-64.958344
"68006","1968-02-01T10:00",28.705,-64.925003
"68006","1968-02-01T11:00",28.450001,-64.966667
"68006","1968-02-01T12:00",28.21386,-64.911087
"68006","1968-02-01T13:00",27.97802,-64.866966
"68006","1968-02-01T20:00",27.799999,-64.883331
"68006","1968-02-01T21:00",27.6,-64.85183
"68006","1968-02-02T02:00",27.385,-64.946663
"68006","1968-02-02T03:00",27.15167,-64.910004
"68006","1968-02-02T04:00",26.988331,-64.85833
"68006","1968-02-02T05:00",26.816669,-64.883331
"68006","1968-02-03T05:00",24.51667,-64.633331
"68006","1968-02-03T06:00",24.299999,-64.550003
"68006","1968-02-03T07:00",24.116671,-64.466667
"68006","1968-02-03T08:00",23.9125,-64.402496
"68006","1968-02-03T09:00",23.70833,-64.338333
"68006","1968-02-03T10:00",23.495831,-64.290001
"68006","1968-02-03T11:00",23.283331,-64.241669
"68006","1968-02-03T12:00",23.08,-64.175003
"68006","1968-02-03T17:00",23.11515,-64.280296
"68006","1968-02-03T18:00",22.91667,-64.283333
"68006","1968-02-03T19:00",22.700001,-64.26667
"68006","1968-02-03T22:00",22.480869,-64.227539
"68006","1968-02-04T02:00",22.11833,-64.228333
```

restarted program expected fix

Comment: Your CSV data is in lat/lon so you must make sure to set the CRS to EPSG:4326 in the CSV import window

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404682/import-csv-with-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates-in-qgis for more details